# How to find all the strings of the given conditions described?

Tags: string, algorithm

Problem:

1. Given an integer k.
2. There is a **string** composed of **1** and **0**(e.g. '10110'),
   name it *binary code* here.
3. The length of the *binary code* is **2^k+k-1**(e.g. given k is 2, so
   the length of *binary code* is 5)
4. If the length k substring of the *binary code* occurs only once in the *binary code*.

then the *binary code* is what we are looking for.For example:

> Given k is 2 (for example, the length of the matched *binary code* is 5. Code
>   **"10011"** is a match, because its substring of lenght 2 are **"10","00","01","11"**, and all of them occured in the *binary code* only once.). all of such *binary codes* are **"00110"**, **"10011"**,
>   **"11001"**, **"01100"**

I'm looking for an algorithm to find all the *binary codes* of a given k as fast as possible.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you re-phrase your problem statement? Also include your attempt in your question, not as an answer.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I've edited my question and try to make it clear, is there any help for you?

Comment: How you know there is *binary code* for each `k`? I mean conforming to all requirements (especially 4.).

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil If there is no *binary code* match the conditions, then return None is OK. Actually I don't know whether there are *binary codes* for each `k`.

Answer (score 1):

We can model *binary code* as permutation of all combinations of length `k`. We have `2^k` combinations and they can be arranged in `(2^k)!` permutations. It is pretty lot of codes but to fulfill requirement 3. the length `2^k+k-1` means `k-1` suffix of each combination of length `k` has to be `k-1` prefix of next combination. We have first combination of length `k` `2^k - 1` new combinations of length `k` when each new combination adds one new symbol. So we can prune all of those `(2^k)!` pretty fast.

We can model combination of length `k` as binary number. Then each "code" can start with one of those numbers and next number have to have `k-1` bits from previous number and added one new bit 0 or 1. It can be done by shifting to left by 1 and adding 0 or 1 and then mask to `k` bits. The new number can be used only when not have been used so far so we have to remember numbers used. We would generate sequences of length `2^k` which will fulfill above requirements. As result we then transform those sequences to corresponding *binary code*. It means we use all bits from first number and add least bit form all next numbers. Or we can use highest bit form all numbers and add all bits from last.

The resulting code in Erlang:

```
-module(binary_code).

-export([gen/1]).

gen(K) ->
    N = (1 bsl K) - 1,
    gen(N, K, lists:seq(0, N)).

gen(Mask, K, L) ->
    [ [ $0 + B || <<B:1>> <= <<X:K>> ] ++ V
     || X <- L, V <- gen(Mask, Mask, X, [X]) ].

gen(_, 0, _, _) -> [[]];
gen(Mask, N, Prev, Prefix) ->
    P = (Prev bsl 1) band Mask,
    [ [$0 + (X band 1)|V] || X <- [P, P bor 1],
               not lists:member(X, Prefix),
               V <- gen(Mask, N-1, X, [X|Prefix])
              ].
```

Results:

```
44> binary_code:gen(1).
["01","10"]
45> binary_code:gen(2).
["00110","01100","10011","11001"]
46> binary_code:gen(3).
["0001011100","0001110100","0010111000","0011101000",
 "0100011101","0101110001","0111000101","0111010001",
 "1000101110","1000111010","1010001110","1011100010",
 "1100010111","1101000111","1110001011","1110100011"]
47> binary_code:gen(4).
["0000100110101111000","0000100111101011000",
 "0000101001101111000","0000101001111011000",
 "0000101100111101000","0000101101001111000",
 "0000101111001101000","0000101111010011000",
 "0000110010111101000","0000110100101111000",
 "0000110101111001000","0000110111100101000",
 "0000111100101101000","0000111101001011000",
 "0000111101011001000","0000111101100101000",
 "0001001101011110000","0001001111010110000",
 "0001010011011110000","0001010011110110000",
 "0001011001111010000","0001011010011110000",
 "0001011110011010000","0001011110100110000",
 "0001100101111010000","0001101001011110000",
 "0001101011110010000","0001101111001010000",
 [...]|...]
48> length(v(47)).
256
49> binary_code:gen(5).
["000001000110010100111010110111110000",
 "000001000110010100111011010111110000",
 "000001000110010100111110101101110000",
 "000001000110010100111110110101110000",
 "000001000110010101101001110111110000",
 "000001000110010101101001111101110000",
 "000001000110010101101110100111110000",
 "000001000110010101101111101001110000",
 "000001000110010101110110100111110000",
 "000001000110010101111101101001110000",
 "000001000110010110101001110111110000",
 "000001000110010110101001111101110000",
 "000001000110010110111010100111110000",
 "000001000110010110111110101001110000",
 "000001000110010111011010100111110000",
 "000001000110010111110110101001110000",
 "000001000110011101001010110111110000",
 "000001000110011101010010110111110000",
 "000001000110011101101001010111110000",
 "000001000110011101101010010111110000",
 "000001000110011111010010101101110000",
 "000001000110011111010100101101110000",
 "000001000110011111011010010101110000",
 "000001000110011111011010100101110000",
 "000001000110100101011001110111110000",
 "000001000110100101011001111101110000",
 "000001000110100101011100111110110000",
 "000001000110100101011101100111110000",
 [...]|...]
50> length(v(49)).     
65536
```

It seems that number of *binary codes* are `2^(2^(k-1))`. It escalates quickly. For generating of *binary codes* for higher `k` I would recommend use C or ASM. (2^32 = 4,294,967,296 for `k=6`.)

**Edit**:

There is mine [attempt](https://gist.github.com/pichi/7892725) to implement it in C and It works nice.

```
$ ./binary_code 1
01
10
$ ./binary_code 2
00110
01100
10011
11001
$ ./binary_code 3
0001011100
0001110100
0010111000
0011101000
0100011101
0101110001
0111000101
0111010001
1000101110
1000111010
1010001110
1011100010
1100010111
1101000111
1110001011
1110100011
$ time ./binary_code 4 | wc
    256     256    5120

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time ./binary_code 5 | wc
  65536   65536 2424832

real    0m0.053s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m0.000s
$ ./binary_code 6 | head -n 20
000000100001100010100011100100101100110100111101010111011011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110100111101101110101011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110100111111010101110110111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110100111111011011101010111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110101011101001111011011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110101011101001111110110111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110101011101101111010011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110101011101101111110100111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110101011110110111010011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110101011111101101110100111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110100111101010111011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110100111101110101011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110100111111010101110111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110100111111011101010111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110101011101001111011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110101011101001111110111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110101011101111010011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110101011101111110100111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110101011110111010011111100000
000000100001100010100011100100101100110110101011111101110100111100000

$ time ./binary_code 6 | wc
4294967296 4294967296 300647710720

real    123m18.854s
user    183m36.848s
sys     2m33.652s

$ time ./binary_code 6 > /dev/null

real    63m5.656s
user    62m50.808s
sys     0m11.072s
```

It can generate 75MB/s of *binary code* for `k=6`. I have also tried solve it [without recursion](https://gist.github.com/pichi/7892725/c11fa4965343cc3239f6225248ab73a79463933b) but `gcc` has to do something amazing under hood because non-recursive version is about 10% slower then mine first straightforward recursive version.

Comment: Thanks. I can get your idea from your description. But since I'm not familiar with Erlang, Would you please show your idea in C/JAVA/Python/PHP?

Comment: @Snowwolf: I have added C code. I think it's speed can be improved by smaller stack-frame (I don't like global variables.) or even avoiding recursion at all, but it would by much harder.

Comment: @Snowwolf I couldn't resist so I tried it without recursion and it doesn't work.

Comment: And size of stack frame seems doesn't have any effect too. Only branch prediction matters.

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve the problem in the way below:

1. find all the possible substrings of length k and build a digraph
   with these strings as nodes.
2. try to find all paths in the digraph
       which will traverse all the nodes only once. the string composed of
       the nodes of given order in the path is the string matched the given
       condition.

Below is my code in python:
import sys
import types

```
def find_path(s_map, slen):
    res = set()
    if (s_map):
        for i in s_map:
            used = list()
            used.append(i)
            res = find_sub(s_map, used, res, slen)

    return len(res),res

def find_sub(s_map, used, res, slen):
    if (set(used) != set(s_map)):
        for x in s_map[used[-1]]:
            if (x not in used):
                used.append(x)
                print used

                if (set(used) == set(s_map)):
                    sub = used[:-1]
                    s = ''
                    for i in sub:
                        s += i[0]
                    s += used[-1]
                    print s, len(s), len(s_map)
                    if (len(s) == slen):
                        print s
                        res.add(s)
                else:
                    find_sub(s_map, used, res, slen)
                used.remove(x)
            else:
                continue

    return res

def build_map(s_list):
    s_map = dict()

    for s in s_list:
        l = (s_list[0:])
        l.remove(s)
        s_map[s] = [i for i in l if s[1:] == i[:-1]]

    return s_map        

def binary_strings(k):
    if type(k) is types.IntType:
        return [(str(bin(i))[2:]).rjust(k, '0') for i in xrange(2 ** k) ]

def main():
    print find_path(build_map(binary_strings(2)), 2**2+2-1)
    print find_path(build_map(binary_strings(3)), 2**3+3-1)
    print find_path(build_map(binary_strings(4)), 2**4+4-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys(exit(main()))
```